# Order array by predefined rules

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have an array of currencies `["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "DKK", "SKE", "USD", "SEK", "BGN"]`. I would like to order it by moving predefined list if the currency is present to the beginning of array. Predefined list is `['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP']`.
So in this case it should return `['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP', 'SEK', BGN']`.

But in case unfiltered array does not contain all values in predifined list it should also order it correctly. For example : `["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "LTU", "ZGN"]` should look like `['EUR', 'NOK', 'GBP', 'LTU', 'ZGN'`

I was trying to sort it using this function:

```
list.sort(c => ['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP'].indexOf(c))
```

but it puts all predefined currencies at the end of the list, not at the from. Maybe there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: the callback for `.sort()` takes to arguments - the first and second comparator.  you can do this same thing but with `list.sort(( c, d ) => [...].indexOf(c) > [...].indexOf(d) ? 1 : [...].indexOf(c) < [...].indexOf(d) ? -1 : 0);` but, adjust the `>` and `<` signs as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and a hash table for the sort order. If the value is not in the hash table, the original order is taken.

```js
var order = ['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP'],
    orderObj = Object.create(null),
    data = ["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "DKK", "SKE", "USD", "SEK", "BGN"];

// generate hash table
order.forEach((a, i) => orderObj[a] = i + 1);

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = data.map((el, i) => { return { index: i, value: orderObj[el] || Infinity }; });

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value || a.index - b.index);

// assigning the resulting order
var data = mapped.map(el => data[el.index]);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Good answer. But since i'm using ES6 the last code part can be written in one line `data
        .map((el, i) => { return { index: i, value: order[el] || 1000 }; })
        .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value || a.index - b.index)
        .map(el => d[el.index]);`

Comment: Instead of `1000`, better use the proper value `Infinity` :-)

Comment: @Bergi, great idea :-)

Answer (score 2):

I guess this can also be achieved like this

```js
Array.prototype.intersect = function(a) {
  return this.filter(e => a.includes(e));
};
Array.prototype.excludes = function(a) {
  return this.filter(e => !a.includes(e));
};
var getCur = (p,c) => p.intersect(c).concat(c.excludes(p)),
      cur1 = ["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "DKK", "SKE", "USD", "SEK", "BGN"],
      cur2 = ["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "LTU", "ZGN"],
       pdl = ['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP', 'SEK', 'BGN'];
console.log(getCur(pdl,cur1));
console.log(getCur(pdl,cur2));
```

Comment: Since you're using ES6 anyway, better go for `a.includes(e)`

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution. :-)

```js
//custom index of
Array.prototype.customIndexOf = function(a){
  return this.indexOf(a) === -1 ? Infinity : this.indexOf(a);
}

let orderArr = ['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP'];


/*test case 1*/
let urList = ["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "DKK", "SKE", "USD", "SEK", "BGN"];
urList.sort((a, b) => { return orderArr.customIndexOf(a) - orderArr.customIndexOf(b); });
console.log(urList); //[ 'EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP', 'SEK', 'BGN' ]

/*test case 2*/
let newList = ["GBP", "EUR", "NOK", "LTU", "ZGN"];

newList.sort((a, b) => { return orderArr.customIndexOf(a) - orderArr.customIndexOf(b); });
console.log(newList); //[ 'EUR', 'NOK', 'GBP', 'LTU', 'ZGN' ]
```

hope this is what u need :-)

Comment: Why `Number.MAX_VALUE`? Just use `Infinity`.

Comment: anything.. we need one big value.. for comparison.. :)

Comment: But how big? Is 10000 enough? Is 2^31 enough? Better use the biggest value available - `Infinity`. Admittedly, as `indexOf` can't return anything larger than an array index, so anything above 2^32 will do, and `Number.MAX_VALUE` is way above that so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

var tabCurrency = ['GBP', 'EUR', 'NOK', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'USD', 'SEK', 'BGN'];

var tabPredef = ['EUR', 'USD', 'DKK', 'SKE', 'NOK', 'GBP'];

var newTabGood = [];

```
    tabPredef.forEach(function (itemPredef, indexPref) {

         var indexTemp;

         tabCurrency.forEach(function (itemCurrency, indexCurrency) {
               if(itemPredef == itemCurrency)
               {
                  newTabGood.push(itemPredef);
                  indexTemp = indexCurrency;
               }
         })

         tabCurrency.splice(indexTemp, 1)
   }) 


 var resultat = newTabGood.concat(tabCurrency);

 console.log(resultat)
```