# Sort array of objects by string following the order given by another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have an array of objects with the _id index

```
[{
    _id: 'zzz'
}, {
    _id: 'abc'
}, {
    _id: 'xxx'
}, {
    _id: '123'
}, {
    _id: 'several other objects not in the array'
}]
```

I also have an array like this

```
['abc', '123', 'xxx', 'zzz']
```

how can I make sure that the array of objects is correctly ordered by the array given?

I'm using 2 for loops but really looks ugly, and I'm sure there's a better way for this. thanks!

Comment: Another similar question that's useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671695/order-array-by-predefined-rules (also answered by Nina Scholz )

Comment: elegant, thank you